# Android: How to grab username info after login and display welcome 'username' in MainActivity

Tags: android, authentication, textview, sharedpreferences

I have done alot of search for this and most of them are not for android.

I am using sharedpref to save the username in session until logout. I would like to display welcome 'username' in the mainactivity.

. For now I would like a sample code on grabbing the 'username' within the mainactivity class thats saved in sharedprefs and display it in textview.

Below is my login class that opens the mainActivity

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("username", username);
        editor.commit();

        if(prefs.getString("username", null)!=null)
        {Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Customer.class); 
        startActivity(i);}

        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check Login
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();


            if(username.equals("1111")){
                lblResult.setText("Login successful.");

               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                            } 
            else if(username.equals("2222")){
                lblResult.setText("Login successful.");

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Close the application
            finish();

                }
            });   }
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{

    TextView selection;
    CustomerListItem[] items = { 
            new CustomerListItem("Start Trip", StartTripActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Clock in", ClockinActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Log Out", LogoutActivity.class)};
    private TextView resultsTxt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.customer);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CustomerListItem>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);
showname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showname);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, items[position].getActivity());
        startActivityForResult(intent, position);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            // Perform different actions based on from which activity is
            // the application returning:
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case 0:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the 
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the                     
break;
                case 2:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the                    
break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            resultsTxt.setText("Canceled");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is 'editor.commit();' commented out? You must use commit() to save the editor changes.

Comment: just updated it but it seems to work better without the editor.commit() it seems I have to login/logout twice oppose to comment out it would do it once to complete the process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try...

In your login Activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("username", username).commit();
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
startActivity(i);
```

In your main activity...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String username = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(...) here

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
        username = prefs.getString("username", "UNKNOWN");

        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my post with my codes and i have more than one login and each have diff. username to diff. activity. I need to be able to display that username to that specific activity. I wasn't able to work with the code you have given me. What could i be missing or where is the correct location to place the code? Thanks =)

Comment: @merrill: Urrrm, for `prefs.edit().putString("username", ...)` instead use `"username01"`, `"username02"` etc etc for the different login credentials. Then simply use `prefs.getString(...)` with each different username in each different Activity.

Comment: @MisterSquonk is the word "MyApp" the name of the class? As for me would it be as "Login"?

Comment: @merrill: The word `MyApp` can be anything you want it to be. What happens is the first time I use `getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);` it tries to find an XML preferences file called MyApp.xml in the app storage space. If the file doesn't exist then it is created. From then on any use of `MyApp` will refer to that XML file. You can choose any name and even have multiple preference files - as long as the Activity which is 'getting' the preferences uses the same name as the Activity which 'put' the preferences then it will work.

Comment: @MisterSquonk Where does the "MyApp" save? I couldn't find it in any folder within the project not even under assets folder. I also would like to say that it display Welcome Null. Im wondering what im missing there

Comment: @merrill: The XML preference files are created by the Android OS at runtime. I'm not sure the exact directory where they are stored but it will be somewhere in `/data/data/<your.package.name>/` on the actual device's internal memory. I don't understand what you mean by "Welcome Null".

Comment: @MisterSquonk I added a TextView with "Welcome " + username. It displayed Welcome Null. As you can see in my Login there was a word Null, for that line was suppose to check if username is still in session and if yes it would go straight to the mainscreen.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should pass the username as an extra so the next activity can grab it. Put this in your login activity:

```
String username = prefs.getString("username");

Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
// this is where you should pass the username
i.putExtra("username", username);
startActivity(i);
```

After that, put this in your MainActivity, probably in the `onCreate` method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainview);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras.containsKey("username")) {
        String username = extras.getString("username");

        // put whatever code you want here to show the username

    }
}
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: I updated my post with my codes and i have more than one login and each have diff. username to diff. activity. I need to be able to display that username to that specific activity. I wasn't able to work with the code you have given me. What could i be missing or where is the correct location to place the code? Thanks =)